# Get $1 capture group with dynamic RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, capture-group

I was curious if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here. I want to use a variable inside the expression but for some reason when I try to, it doesn't seem to grab the search term with the `$1`.

This returns correctly:

```
$('.content').html(function(_,i) {
  return  i.replace(/(cat)/gi, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
});
```

For some reason, this does not:

```
$('.content').html(function(_,i) {
  var customVariable = 'cat';
  var pattern = new RegExp(customVariable,'gi');
  return  i.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
});
```

I'm very new to capture groups in RegExp and I couldn't find anyone else having this issue so I assume I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: It's gonna cost you more than $1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot about the brackets:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('(' + customVariable + ')','gi');
```

`$1` is a backreference to group 1 and you do not have any.

Actually, you can find [more about backreferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in JavaScript `replace` on MDN Web site. It is true that in case you do not want to match any text before or after the alternatives, you just do not need to set up a capturing group, since when using a regex the whole matched text can be referenced with a `$&` pattern (in your case, you just need to replace `$1` with `$&`).

> `$&`     Inserts the matched substring.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define a sub-pattern, since you're highlighting the entire match. You can simply do:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(customVariable, 'gi');
i.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
```

`$&` refers to the entire pattern.

Comment: @daless14: `$&` is a special syntax in **replacement string** to refer to the text matched by the whole regular expression.